Basis for a topology in $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$
I'm starting my studies in topology (on my own) and sometimes I have a hard time seeing how to use the concepts. I need help with this problem:

Let $X$ be the set of all ($n \times x$) matrices of real numbers. For each $a = (a_{ij})$ and $r>0$, let
$$
U_{r}(a) = \{(b_{ij}) \mid \forall i,j : |a_{ij} - b_{ij}| < r\}. 
$$
Show that these sets are the basis for some topology on $X$.

My attempted demonstration:
If $\alpha \in X$, we have that $\alpha \in U_{r}(\alpha)$ (then the union of these things result $X$).
Let $\alpha \in X$ and $U_{r_1}(x), U_{r_2}(y) \in \{U_{r}(a)\}$ such that $\alpha \in U_{r_1}(x) \cap U_{r_2}(y)$. Then
$$
|\alpha_{i,j} - b_{i,j}| < r_1 
\quad\text{and}\quad 
|\alpha_{ij} - c_{ij}| < r_2, 
$$
where $r_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$. Thus, because of the density of $\mathbb{R}$, we can take $r_3 < \min \{r_1 , r_2\}$. Then
\begin{align}
U_{r_3} (\alpha) = \{(d_{i,j}) \mid \forall i,j : |\alpha_{ij} - d_{ij}|<r_3\} 
&\implies U_{r_3}(\alpha) \subseteq U_{r_1}(x)
\quad\text{and}\quad 
U_{r_3}(\alpha) \subseteq U_{r_2}(y) \\[4pt]
&\implies U_{r_3}(\alpha) \subseteq U_{r_1}(x) \cap U_{r_2}(y)
\end{align}
Finally, $x \in U_{r_3}(\alpha) \subseteq U_{r_1}(x) \cap U_{r_2}(y)$.
That's right? (This exercise is from the Dugundji book.)

Seems fine to me.

You are asking for solution verification. Description of the tag: "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplicate questions."

I’m voting to close this question because it does not meet the standards of the tag "solution-verification".

A shortcut is to identify $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb R)$ with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$and then show $U_r(a)$ is the open ball of some familiar metric.
